# Changing the color of a texbox with a table cell VB ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have created a textbox within a cell of a table and I am using this to take input from a user and display it on a webpage. I however cant get the background of the textbox to change when the user clicks in side the textbox, normally I would use simple CSS for this but as the textbox is inside a table cell I cant seem to be able to work out how to do this. Any Ideas on how to approach this?

I have the following VB code to generate and populate my table.

**VB**

```
 Protected Sub GenerateTable(noOfRows As Integer)
    Dim table As Table
    Dim row As TableRow
    Dim cell As TableCell
    Dim tb As TextBox
    Dim lbl As Label
    table = Table1
    table.ID = "Table1"

    For i As Integer = 1 To noOfRows Step 1
        row = New TableRow()
        For j As Integer = 0 To 1 Step 1
            cell = New TableCell()
            If j = 1 Then
                tb = New TextBox()
                tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" & i & "Col_" & j
                cell.Controls.Add(tb)

            ElseIf j = 0 Then
                lbl = New Label()
                lbl.ID = "Label" & i
                lbl.Text = "Volume " & i
                cell.Controls.Add(lbl)
            End If
            row.Cells.Add(cell)
        Next
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    ViewState("RowsCount") = noOfRows
    Session("RowsCount") = noOfRows
End Sub
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Table class="Table1" ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>

        <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddVolume" class="btnVolumeBreak" runat="server"  Text="Add Volume Break"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add your CSS Classes for both a Focused and UnFocused TextBox:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .UnFocusedCssClass
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .FocusedCssClass
    {
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
</style>
```

Next add this Javascript to your ASPX/ASCX Markup:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function UnFocus(targetControl) {
        targetControl.className = 'UnFocusedCssClass';
    }

    function Focus(targetControl) {
        targetControl.className = 'FocusedCssClass';
    }
</script>
```

Finally, wire up the Javascript to the Textboxes you add to your cell using the Attributes Property:

```
tb.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "Focus(this);")
tb.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "UnFocus(this);")
cell.Controls.Add(tb)
```